# Are descriptives and depictives the same thing

Tags: meaning

I know depictives are secondary predicates describing how a certain action took place like in 'I ate the meat **raw**'.

But what are descriptives? I saw on wikipedia that they are just a different name for depictives, but I found no other place where it is explained what descriptives are exactly or if they are the same thing as depictives.

Can anyone explain or provide a reference?

Comment: I believe they are synonymous as far as predicatives are concerned. They contrast with 'resultative', compare "They served the coffee black" (depictive) ~"He talked himself hoarse" (resultative).

Comment: Terminology is sadly not consensual in such matters. Linnaean taxonomy was a step in the right direction in the sciences. // I Like Kullenberg's use of the following terms to describe prenominal adjective (/adjective phrase) functions: **(a) classifiers** (putting into / recognising fixed classes ... grading into compounds) eg polar bear, red kite, nuclear reaction // **(b) identifiers** (using a description to pick out a temporary subset as in 'Pass me the red folder, would you, Pete.') // **(c) descriptors** (purely tacking on additional information as in 'A small red bird flew by.')

Comment: We're not talking about modifiers here, but predicative complements, specifically of the depictive kind. I don't see any problems with the terminology.

Comment: Ah, BillJ's royal we. // I do have to concede that Kullenberg's terminology is due originally to Warren. Decent responses add attributions and don't sound like they derive from some infallible, unchallengeable source.